# Pull database data into a mulitiple select dropdown

Tags: jquery

I'm currently having trouble with fetching data for my dropdown. What I currently get is a repeated dropdown menu (one project + one dropdown).

```
<div class="form-group" style="width: 200px;">
     @foreach (var project in Model.PModels["SAMPLEPROJ"] as Projects)
           {
              <select name="Project" id="Project" multiple="multiple">
              Project.append(<option>@project.ProjectNo</option>).val(); 
              </select> 
           }
</div>
```

How can I get all the values on one dropdown only? Thank you very much!

Comment: Write <select name="Project" id="Project" multiple="multiple"> out side of foreach. :)

Comment: Bu this one:  @foreach (var project in Model.PModels["SAMPLEPROJ"] as Projects), is my reference to fetch the projects.

Comment: I mean to say put only your <option> tag inside foreach. And select tag start before foreach and close it after foreach.

Comment: I didn't work. It doesn't read <option>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, just move it like this:

```
<div class="form-group" style="width: 200px;">
    <select name="Project" id="Project" multiple="multiple">
    @foreach (var project in Model.PModels["SAMPLEPROJ"] as Projects)
    {
            <option>@project.ProjectNo</option>
    }
    </select> 
</div>
```

Comment: try the updated code.. remove the `Project.append(` and `).val();`

Comment: Still didn't work. I' am thinking of doing this thing using ajax.

Comment: what's the `error` or the `output` if there's no error?

Comment: It doesn't prompt an error but it still replicate the dropdown. Anyway, I'am trying to solve this using ajax. But it says 'no matches found' .

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

option tag should be like as below. You can use value attribute if you want. And option text should be your project name(whatever your project field: title, name...).

```
   <div class="form-group" style="width: 200px;">
      <select name="Project" id="Project" multiple="multiple">
      @foreach (var project in Model.PModels["SAMPLEPROJ"] as Projects)
      {
          <option value="@project.ProjectNo">@project.ProjectNo</option>
      }
      </select> 
   </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know more about mvc razor but i can suggest to use ListBox or ListBoxFor helper to create multiselect dropdown.